# Searching messages returns more results when I decrease receivedDate range

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to search messages using Microsoft Graph. I performed two searches and specified different `received` ranges in both of them:

1. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users('user_id')/messages?$search="received>=2018-08-07T22:00:00Z AND received<=2018-09-28T22:00:00Z"&$select=id&$top=100` - I got 240 results
2. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users('user_id')/messages?$search="received>=2018-08-07T22:00:00Z AND received<=2018-09-14T22:00:00Z"&$select=id&$top=100` - I got 275 results.

As you can see, I've decreased the `received` range from `[2018-08-07; 2018-09-28]` to `[2018-08-07; 2018-09-14]`, but I see more messages. Moreover, I only used a `received` filter.

Why would I receive more results using a smaller date window?

Comment: 240 and 275 messages means total. I also followed `@odata.nextLink` and combined results from all requests. This request was performed on production environment via C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you find that there are more than messages when you use a smaller date window.

I have tried this, and it works. If you have this problem often, you can submit a issue on [the Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues)